# Use global scope (count) in a where clause of a local scope

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have posts with multiple tags and added the posts_count as a global scope to my Tag model

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('postCount', function($builder) {
        $builder->withCount('posts');
    });
}
```

Now I want to select the "popluar" tags

```
 public function scopePopular($query)
{
    return $query->where('posts_count', '>', 1)
                 ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc');
}
```

However this is not working with the message

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts_count' in 'where clause'`

The generated query looks like

```
select `tags`.*, 
  (select count(*) 
  from `posts` 
  inner join `post_tag` 
  on `posts`.`id` = `post_tag`.`post_id` 
  where `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id`) 
as `posts_count` 
from `tags` 
where `posts_count` > 1 
order by `posts_count` desc
```

since the result is selected "as posts_count" I'd expect the query to work

UPDATE:

Tag tables

```
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name')->unique();

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('tag_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('tags')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('post_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('posts')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Post Table

```
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('title');

        $table->string('slug')->unique();

        $table->text('image')->nullable();

        $table->string('status');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('set null');

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
    });
```

Comment: can you add your table ?

Comment: added the tags and post table, aswell as the post_tag table

Comment: try to use `having` instead of `where` - `return $query->having('posts_count', '>', 1)
                 ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc');`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'posts_count' is used in HAVING clause

Comment: return $query->having('posts_count', '>', 1) ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc')->groupBy(['id', 'posts_count']);

Comment: try to use `whereHas` like this : `$query->whereHas('posts_count', '>', 1)` !

Comment: Both do not sem to work, however the following seems to work: `return $query->has('posts', '>', 1)->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc');` found on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/withcount-where-clause